# From jquery to angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

i am using the below format to get a JSON object from my localhost. The JSON is pretty complicated and lengthy so , using jquery to populate the HTML is getting complicated.

```
function processmsg(msg) {
        var jobj = JSON.parse(msg);
        if (typeof jobj === 'object')
        {
            // Parse the JSON
            }
            document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = globalTag;

        }
    }

    function waitForMsg() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "1.json",

            cache: false,
            timeout: 50000,

            success: function (data) {
                processmsg(data);
                if (!data) {
                    setTimeout(
                        waitForMsg,
                        1000
                    );
                };
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                setTimeout(waitForMsg, 15000);
                processmsg("error");
            }

        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        waitForMsg();
        processmsg("loading");
    });
```

I would like to use the format like {{jobj.entries}}. something like this. This can be done on angularJS. can you guys please suggest me how to do the same in angular ?

i want to query the JSON every 1 min and when the data is found i want to cancel the interval. I dono how to do it in angularjs.

==================update================
i got below code snippet. It is working fine, But how do i stop the url query once the json object is obtained..

```
var app = angular.module('urlanalyzer', []);

    app.controller('jsonController', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.getData = function(){
        var url = "{% static "" %}tmp/{{url_hash}}/{{url_json}}";
        $http.get(url)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
          });
      };
      if (!$scope.data){
        setInterval($scope.getData, 2000);
      }
```

The issue here is the json object will be available after 3 sec only.

Comment: You shoul play with angular.js before starting an app. Read documentations, try create simple aplication, hello world app, use $http, $timeout, dependency injection etc. I think it is not the right time to start developing app with angular.js

Comment: I got the below code snippet.added to the description

Comment: Why do you need using interval? Angular.js has own $interval service please look at [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), Also, you should set $scope.data = data in success function and cancel the interval promise if success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('urlanalyzer', []);

app.controller('jsonController', ['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  $scope.getData = function(){
    var url = "{% static "" %}tmp/{{url_hash}}/{{url_json}}";
    $http.get(url)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if(!data)
             $timeout(function(){
                $scope.getData()
             }, 2000)
          else{
             $scope.myData = data.data? data.data:data;
             $scope.showError = false;
          }


      })
       .error(function(msg) {
          $timeout(function(){
              $scope.getData()
          }, 2000)
          $scope.processMessage(msg)
      });
  };
  $scope.processMessage = function(msg){
      if(angular.isString(msg))
       $scope.errorMessage = msg;
     else if(angular.isObject(msg)){
        $scope.errorMessage = msg.message // the property you want;
     }
     $scope.showError = true;
  }
  $scope.getData();
}])
```

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="jsonController">
      <div ng-show="showError">
        {{errorMessage}}
      </div>
      <div id="myDatacontainer">
           //you can bind any propery of your data by using angular direvtives
           //look at ng-bing, ng-if etc. directives
          {{myData.name}} ...
      </div>
 </div>
```

Hope it help.

Comment: data.data? data.data:data what does this mean ? the loop terminates  as expected. THanks a lot.

Comment: sometime server response expected data properties as child propery. Just check if is child or not. Complately depends on your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have following JSON data stored in a scope variable named `data`:

```
$scope.data = {
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

Then you write your HTML in the following way like:

```
<div>
    Boolean: {{data.boolean}}
</div>
<div>
    Number: {{data.number * 2}}
</div>
<div>
    Array:
    <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.object"> {{key}} : {{value}}</p>
</div>
Another way to bind <div ng-bind="data.string"></div>
```

Here you can stop your call. You can use enhanced angular service [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) for this:

```
$scope.getData = function(){
    var url = "{% static "" %}tmp/{{url_hash}}/{{url_json}}";
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        $interval.cancel($scope.intervalObject);    // cancel the interval when data is loaded
     });
};

if (!$scope.data){
    $scope.intervalObject = $interval($scope.getData, 2000);
}
```

Comment: The problem is , i have a jquery. I am unable to pass the json data to Angular $scope.

Comment: Then use angular's `$http` service for AJAX call.

Comment: thats the help i need. The angular code which i metioned above works . But it keeps on querying. I need to stop it once the data is available. i dono how to do that.

Comment: for some reason i get this error. :(Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=urlanalyzer&p1=Erro…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (!$scope.data){
    setInterval($scope.getData, 2000);
  }
```

since `$scope.data` is not set it'll continue calling the request(since you are not setting `$scope.data` anywhere).

Edit: Also, use angularjs `$interval` since it's the angular way of using `setInterval` and it keeps track of the `$digest` cycle